# Flutter: Building list from querysnapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a list based on this example from google.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase#8

Somehow, there is an error in this line

```
return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
```

with the error message: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'

This example used to work but there was probably an upgrade and now this is not working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Baby Names',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Baby Name Votes')),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.name),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(record.name),
          trailing: Text(record.votes.toString()),
          onTap: () => print(record),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Record {
  final String name;
  final int votes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['votes'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        votes = map['votes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Replacing Deprecated Code

According to the latest Firebase Firestore documents for Flutter, you have to use the getter `docs` instead of `documents`.

```dart
QuerySnapshot query = ...
List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = query.docs;
```

`documents` has been deprecated and will be removed in coming updates. [More info](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querysnapshot)

## Fix for Error

```dart
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
print('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}, Has Data: ${snapshot.hasData}'); // Only for debugging
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      }
      else return LinearProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: ok, I changed it to docs and there is no error message but nothing was shown on page and there is no error message.  I have made mistakes somewhere else too.

Comment: Can you give some more details

Comment: it is only showing linear progress indicator as if snapshot has no data